# CodeEditor example in pyqt

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt4

I tried to learn some Qt (PyQt). To do so I used the [Code Editor example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-widgets-codeeditor-example.html) of the docs. The highlighting of the current line works fine. The line number however do not show.

Actually the `LineNumberArea.paintEvent` is not even called. Subequently also not `CodeEditor.lineNumberAreaPaintEvent`. As far as I understood it the paintEvent of the number bars should be called by periodically. Or at least when there is an `updateRequest` or scroll event (called by `CodeEditor.updateLineNumberArea`).

Here is my take to port the code from c++ to python:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

import numpy as np

class LineNumberArea(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, editor):
        super().__init__()
        self.editor = editor


    def sizeHint(self):
        return Qsize(self.editor.lineNumberAreaWidth(), 0)


    def paintEvent(self, event):
        print('LineNumberArea.paintEvent')
        self.editor.lineNumberAreaPaintEvent(event)


class CodeEditor(QPlainTextEdit):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.lineNumberArea = LineNumberArea(self)

        self.connect(self, SIGNAL('blockCountChanged(int)'), self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth)
        self.connect(self, SIGNAL('updateRequest(QRect,int)'), self.updateLineNumberArea)
        self.connect(self, SIGNAL('cursorPositionChanged()'), self.highlightCurrentLine)

        self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth(0)


    def lineNumberAreaWidth(self):
        """ This method has been slightly modified (use of log and uses actual
        font rather than standart.) """
        n_lines = self.blockCount()
        digits = np.ceil(np.log10(n_lines)) + 1
        return digits * QFontMetrics(self.font()).width('9') + 3


    def updateLineNumberAreaWidth(self, _):
        print('CodeEditor.updateLineNumberAreaWidth: margin = {}'.format(self.lineNumberAreaWidth()))
        self.setViewportMargins(self.lineNumberAreaWidth(), 0, 0, 0)


    def updateLineNumberArea(self, rect, dy):
        print('CodeEditor.updateLineNumberArea: rect = {}, dy = {}'.format(rect, dy))

        if dy:
            self.lineNumberArea.scroll(0, dy)
        else:
            self.lineNumberArea.update(0, rect.y(), self.lineNumberArea.width(),
                                       rect.height())

        print('CodeEditor.updateLineNumberArea: rect.contains(self.viewport().rect()) = {}'.format(rect.contains(self.viewport().rect())))
        if rect.contains(self.viewport().rect()):
            self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth(0)


    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)

        cr = self.contentsRect();
        self.lineNumberArea.setGeometry(QRect(cr.left(), cr.top(),
                                        self.lineNumberAreaWidth(), cr.height()))

    def lineNumberAreaPaintEvent(self, event):
        print('CodeEditor.lineNumberAreaPaintEvent')
        painter(self.lineNumberArea)
        painter.fillRect(event.rect(), Qt.lightGray)

        block = self.firstVisibleBlock()
        blockNumber = block.blockNumber()
        top = self.blockBoundingGeometry(block).translated(self.contentOffset()).top()
        bottom = top + self.blockBoundingRect(block).height()

        # Just to make sure I use the right font
        height = QFontMetrics(self.font()).height()
        while block.isValid() and (top <= event.rect().bottom()):
            if block.isVisible() and (bottom >= event.rect().top()):
                number = str(blockNumber + 1)
                painter.setPen(Qt.black)
                painter.drawText(0, top, lineNumberArea.width(), height,
                                 Qt.AlignRight, number)

            block = block.next()
            top = bottom
            bottom = top + self.blockBoundingRect(block).height()
            blockNumber += 1


    def highlightCurrentLine(self):
        extraSelections = []

        if not self.isReadOnly():
            selection = QTextEdit.ExtraSelection()

            lineColor = QColor(Qt.yellow).lighter(160)

            selection.format.setBackground(lineColor)
            selection.format.setProperty(QTextFormat.FullWidthSelection, True)
            selection.cursor = self.textCursor()
            selection.cursor.clearSelection()
            extraSelections.append(selection)
        self.setExtraSelections(extraSelections)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    txt = CodeEditor()
    txt.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

In case it matters:
python: 3.4.3, PyQt: 4.8.6, OS: RHEL 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example looks mostly right. The issue with the missing paint events is caused by not setting a parent on the `LineNumberArea` widget. So you just need:

```
class LineNumberArea(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, editor):
        super().__init__(editor)
```

Also, the `lineNumberAreaPaintEvent` method has a few problems, but they're easily fixed:

```
def lineNumberAreaPaintEvent(self, event):
    # missing constructor
    painter = QPainter(self.lineNumberArea)
    ...
    # no need to use QFontMetrics
    height = self.fontMetrics().height()
    ...
            # missing self
            painter.drawText(0, top, self.lineNumberArea.width(), height,
                             Qt.AlignRight, number)
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with your implementation of `lineNumberAreaWidth`, as it doesn't seem to give the right results. The original implementation works exactly as expected, though (and is also much faster):

```
def lineNumberAreaWidth(self):
    digits = 1
    count = max(1, self.blockCount())
    while count >= 10:
        count /= 10
        digits += 1
    space = 3 + self.fontMetrics().width('9') * digits
    return space
```